# Divergence of the magnetic field $H$

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, field-theory, maxwell-equations, magnetic-moment

it is known (although I have not found much information about it on books and websites) that, while the divergence of $B$ is always zero ($\nabla\cdot B = 0$), we cannot say the same about $H$: the divergence of $H$ is zero only if the medium is homogeneous.

In fact (for instance suppose the medium to be isotropic and so its permeability to be a scalar quantity):

$$\nabla\cdot H = \nabla\cdot [\frac{B}{\mu(r)}]$$

where $\mu(r)=\mu_0\mu_r(r)$.

If the medium is homogeneous, the permeability $\mu(r)$ does not depend on the position r and can be taken out of the divergence, which therefore concides with the divergence of B, which is 0. But if the medium is inhomogeneous, the divergence of H in general will not be zero.

This question (which has been presented to me in this way during a university lecture) has raised two questions to me:

1. When we say that the medium must be homogeneous in order to get a solenoidal magnetic field H, what do we mean? Should the source (for instance, a magnet) be homogeneous, or the source and the space around it? If it is the second one, an example of this situation is this:

[image]

But if it is the source that should be not homogeneous, it is not the case (unless we suppose that the magnetic permeability of that magnet depends on r).

2. From a math point of view, the reason of $\nabla\cdot H \neq 0$ is clear. Now I need a graph visualization of this. This fact means that B is solenoidal, but H not. So I think their field lines will be a lot different: for B if I take a little volume, the flux will be 0, for H not. Do you have a picture which shows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Question 1

If the source and the space around it are homogeneous, then you definitely have $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = 0$.  However, there are also some circumstances where you have a discontinuity in $\mu$ but still have $\nabla \cdot \vec{H} = 0$ everywhere.  An example would be a long cylinder of linear magnetic material of radius $R$, with a free current running down the middle.  Due to the symmetry of the situation, $\vec{H}$ only points in the tangential direction (not the radial or longitudinal directions), and any such field is divergence-free.

Your diagram, on the other hand, is *not* a good example of this, for the simple reason that it is not a linear magnetic medium!  It is easy to see that in that diagram, $\vec{H}$ is not parallel to $\vec{B}$ inside the magnet, which is required by the relation $\vec{H} = \vec{B}/\mu$.

#### Question 2

If $\vec{M}$ is known, we can easily figure out where the field lines of $\vec{H}$ begin and end (and vice versa.)  Specifically, since $\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$, we have
$$
0 = \mu_0 \nabla \cdot \vec{B} = \nabla \cdot \vec{H} + \nabla \cdot \vec{M} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \nabla \cdot \vec{H} = - \nabla \cdot \vec{M}.
$$
In particular, we can define a fictitious "magnetic charge" $\rho_m = - \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$;  and in the absence of free currents, $\nabla \times \vec{H} = 0$.  The field lines for $\vec{H}$ will then be exactly we would expect from an *electrostatic* field with an *electric* charge density $\rho_m$.  In particular, the field lines of $\vec{H}$ will flow from points where $\rho_m > 0$ to points where $\rho_m < 0$.  Since $\rho_m = - \nabla \cdot \vec{M}$, it's not too hard to see that field lines of $\vec{H}$ end where field lines of $\vec{M}$ begin, and vice versa.

In fact, one can use the entire technology of electrostatics to solve problems in magnetostatics via this correspondence.  One can use a "Coulomb's Law" for $\vec{H}$, or one can define a potential $V_m$ for which $\vec{H} = - \nabla V_m$ and then leverage our knowledge of Poisson's equation ($\nabla^2 V_m = - \rho_m$).  Given all of these correspondences, one can easily understand why many early physicists thought that magnetism was due to another type of charge that behaved like electric charge, rather than due to currents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A last question: in case of a linear permanent magnet in vacuum, will the divergence of H be different from 0 only at the magnet-vacuum boundary (so at the magnet edges) or in any point of space (also inside the air and inside the magnet)?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo:  If the magnetization of the magnetic material is uniform, then $\nabla \cdot \vec{M} \neq 0$ only at the boundaries, and so the same is true of $\nabla \cdot \vec{H}$.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that $\rm{div}\mathbf{B}=0$ *always* and *everywhere* but even if $\mathbf{B}=\mu \mathbf{H}$ with $\mu=const$ inside a homogeneous magnetic material it is *not* true that $\rm{div}\mathbf{H}=0$ because surface poles develop at the boundaries where $\mu_r$ jumps from vacuum $1$ to something $\mu_r >1$ inside the material.

In fact, these poles counteract, i.e., oppose the B-field and is the source of what is usually called the demagnetization field.